# SQL Constraint: date A is before date B -- How?

Tags: sql, constraints

I'm creating an SQL table that needs the fields *from=date* and *to=date* but I'd like to make a constraint so that *to* cannot be before *from*. My program will check for it but I'd like to learn how to enforce it with SQL. 
I've written SQL before but never really used constraints and don't know how they work.

So the question is: Using standard SQL, how do I make sure that *From* is before *To*?

Comment: I think your best bet will be using a trigger to enforce the relationship.

Comment: @D.Lambert: that's absolutely unnecessary. A check constraint will cope with this much better and more efficiently.

Comment: Not tested  ALTER TABLE dbo.Vendors ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Vendor_CreditRatingCHECK (From > To)  Not sure how it will deal with null

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
create table foo
(
   from_date date,
   to_date date,
   constraint check_dates check (from_date < to_date)
);
```

Or if you need to apply this to an existing table, use:

```
alter table foo
   add constraint check_dates check (from_date < to_date);
```

The PostgreSQL manual contains a good chapter about check constraints: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2410

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ok for sql server, mysql and oracle

```
ALTER TABLE myTbl
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Dates CHECK (dtFrom < dtTo)
```

Comment: Won't work for MySQL. The engine is limited and does not support check constraints.