# Adding Simple Constraint - Database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add simple constraint in the database. [I follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732269/sql-constraint-date-a-is-before-date-b-how)

My goal: In Tenants table, if LeaseExpirationDate isn't NULL then it must be later than LeaseStartDate.

I tried:

```
alter table Tenants
   add constraint leasedates_check check (leaseexpirationdate is not null or leaseexpirationdate > leasestartdate);
```

Then I try:

```
UPDATE 
  Tenants 
SET 
  leaseexpirationdate = leasestartdate
WHERE
  apartmentnumber = 1 and houseid = 100;
```

The row is updated even if `leaseexpirationdate is not null`. Where am I wrong? Am I not comparing dates right?

Create Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Tenants(
HouseID INT,
ApartmentNumber INT,
LeaseTenantSSN INT NOT NULL,
LeaseStartDate DATE NOT NULL,
LeaseExpirationDate DATE,
Rent DECIMAL(7,2),
LastRentPaidDate DATE,
RentOverdue BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY(HouseID, ApartmentNumber));
```

I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My goal: In Tenants table, if LeaseExpirationDate isn't NULL then it must be later than LeaseStartDate.*
>
> `check(leaseexpirationdate is not null or leaseexpirationdate > leasestartdate)`

This says that `leaseexpirationdate` must not be null, ***or if it is null*** it must be greater than `leasestartdate`. Comparing null isn't very useful. It will return `unknown` which is the third boolean in [SQL's ternary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL).

Instead you want to check that `leaseexpirationdate` is null ***or if it isn't null*** it must be greater than `leasestartdate`.

```
check(leaseexpirationdate is null or leaseexpirationdate > leasestartdate)
```

Answer (score 4):

This constraint:

```
alter table Tenants
   add constraint leasedates_check check (leaseexpirationdate is not null or leaseexpirationdate > leasestartdate);
```

is equivalent to:

```
alter table Tenants
   add constraint leasedates_check check (leaseexpirationdate is not null);
```

Presumably, you seem to intend:

```
  add constraint leasedates_check check (leaseexpirationdate is null or leaseexpirationdate > leasestartdate);
```

Note that the check is for `is null` and `or` is the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql has a special [`infinity` value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE) for datetime types that makes expressing these kinds of rules *saner*. Here, if I'm not mistaken, the null value is used to indicate a lease that does not have an expiry date.

> My goal: In Tenants table, if LeaseExpirationDate isn't NULL then it must be later than LeaseStartDate.

So, the table definition can be:

```
CREATE TABLE "Tenants"(
  "HouseID" INT NOT NULL,
  "ApartmentNumber" INT NOT NULL,
  "LeaseTenantSSN" INT NOT NULL,
  "LeaseStartDate" DATE NOT NULL,
  "LeaseExpirationDate" DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INFINITY',
  "Rent" DECIMAL(7,2),
  "LastRentPaidDate" DATE,
  "RentOverdue" BOOLEAN,

  PRIMARY KEY("HouseID", "ApartmentNumber")
);
```

And, with that the check constraint can be:

```
ALTER TABLE "Tenants"
   ADD CONSTRAINT leasedates_check check ("LeaseExpirationDate" > "LeaseStartDate");
```

@Gordon Linoff's answer above is correct as well, and is the default way most developers approach start / end times & associated constraints in databases.

Also note that Postgresql identifiers are case-insensitive, unless quoted, as in this answer.